# Recommended models for mineral liberation in crushers

Tags: process-engineering

I'm investigating comminution processes at work, and from my studies I know that there are different breakage models for different modes (Compression, attrition, fracture etc).

So far I have only seen population models for ball mills in use. These models use time, size fraction and axial distance in the mill to specify the mass fraction of material at any given location in time.

I am wondering if similar models exist for other comminution devices (Gyratory or Jaw crushers) and if so  what do they look like?

Comment: See also "EPD (Electric Pulse disaggregation)".

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look up the the "Bond Work Index". It's an empirical method for understanding the energy required to achieve certain amounts of comminution (think P80) for a given method and mineral.